# Can't return JSON from Cosmos DB (MongoDB schema) using a NodeJS Azure Function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, function, serverless

I'm trying to retrieve data from the cosmosdb(MongoDB schema) using a azure function. I can log the data but I can't retrieve it to the client. It just shows nothing, whenn I try calling the function using the browser or postman. Any idea how to return this array of mongodb objects?

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import assert from "assert";

const url = "";


const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    MongoClient.connect(url, async (err, db) => {
        let dbo = db.db("MyDB");
    
        var cursor = await dbo.collection("test").find({}).toArray((err, docs) => {

            if(err) {
                context.res = {
                    body: err,
                }
            }
            if (docs) {
                context.res.set('content-type', 'application/json')
                context.res = {
                    status: 200,
                    body: docs
                };

                console.log(context.res );
            }
            else {
                context.res = {
                    status: 400,
                    body: "No docs"
                };
            }

            context.res.headers = { 'Content-Type':'application/json' };

            context.done();

            console.log("DONE");
        });

        db.close();
      
      });


};

export default httpTrigger;
```

Comment: A Promise must be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

const url = "";


const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
try {
    var client =await MongoClient.connect(url , {useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true})
    const db=client.db("test");
    const cursor =db.collection('Users').find({'saying':'English'});
    const docs =await cursor.toArray();
   
    console.log("done")
    context.res={
        status: 200,
        body: docs,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
       }
    
   } catch (error) {
       context.log(error);
       context.res={
        status: 500,
        body: error
       }
   }finally{

      await client.close();
      console.log("closed")
   }
    
    
    
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in the end I did it with Promise.